# Duplicating State in .then function

Tags: reactjs, duplicates, state

```
export default function App() {
  const[ogposts, setOgposts] = useState([])
  const[posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const restApi = 'https://reqres.in/api/users/';

    fetch(restApi)
      .then(res=> res.json())
      .then(res=> {setOgposts(res.data); setPosts(ogposts)})
  },[])

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th> Id </th>
          <th> FirstName </th>
          <th> LastName </th>
          <th> EmailId </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{posts.map((e)=>(<p>{e.id}</p>))}</td>
          <td>{posts.map((e)=>(<p>{e.first_name}</p>))}</td>
          <td>{posts.map((e)=>(<p>{e.last_name}</p>))}</td>
          <td>{posts.map((e)=>(<p>{e.email}</p>))}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the Above code, when I try to duplicate the state of posts to ogposts, but only ogposts has the values of API. When I console.log posts, it shows Empty array. What is wrong in the above code? I want to duplicate the value of ogposts to posts Please help

In the Above code, when I try to duplicate the state of posts to ogposts, but only ogposts has the values of API. When I console.log posts, it shows Empty array. What is wrong in the above code? I want to duplicate the value of ogposts to posts Please help

Comment: `setState` is async. Why not just set both to `res.data`? ...or why even do this at all?

Comment: I need to add an input listener further to filter the table by emails or names.  I need to avoid multiple API calls for every Change. Hence, I am duplicating the state so that the API is called once which is through my fist state i.e ogposts.

Comment: Thank you soo much Tom.  Setting both to res.data worked :D